# selecting records which meet variable number of requirements on foreign table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: `school`, `school_language` and `language`

In `school_language` I insert all languages of a particular school, so if school 1 has languages 1, 2 and 3 I would insert school_language(1,1), school_language(1,2) and school_language(1,3)

My question is how to retrieve all schools with specific list of languages? So if I'd like to retrieve all schools with languages 1 and 2 I would select something like:

```
select count(distinct(s.id)) 
from school s, school_language sl, language l 
where 1=1  
and s.id=sl.school 
and sl.language = l.id 
and l.id=1 
and l.id=2;
```

(but this doesn't work)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all schools with languages 1 and 2:

```
 SELECT S.name, SL.language FROM school S
 INNER JOIN school_language SL ON S.id = SL.school
 WHERE SL.language IN (1,2)
```

Comment: i think that would retrieve all schools with languages 1 OR 2

Comment: Oh, you voted down for the original one? If so, then please cancel it, unless there is still something wrong with this?